# best method of linking to outside of secured script (using SSL)

Tags: html, .htaccess, security, ssl

I have shopping cart script in our site that is setup to be secure (https with SSL certificate). I have links in the script leading to other parts of my site that are not secure (WordPress blog, etc).

In the secure site, if I have links that are not secure ( http ), it triggers a message to user in browser, alerting of unsecured links. If I put the outgoing links in the script as relative links, when the user clicks on them and goes outside of script, it keeps them in secure mode (which we don't want for other parts of our site).

Years ago, I remember having this issue. I think I got around it by using a HTTP Redirect for every outgoing link in the secure site. Using a HTTP Redirect, I would have https://www.example.com/outgoinglink1a redirect to http://www.example.com/outgoinglink1b in the HTTP Redirect. This way, I could put https://www.example.com/outgoinglink1a in the secure site, and when it was clicked, it would lead to http://www.example.com/outgoinglink1b

In modern times, how do I have links in the secure site that lead to other parts of the site that aren't secure, without triggering SSL Error Message to user when they are in Secure part of site? Is using some type of 301 redirect in .htaccess better? Is there another preferred or easier method (than using HTTP Redirects) for accomplishing this?

Thank you for any guidance.

Comment: Why aren't the other parts of the site secure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use https-2-http redirects to the unsecured site to avoid browser warnings.

But for multiple reasons, safety being one of them, I would really advice against using http and https for the same domain, even if lot of big sites still do it. You would ether have to use different cookies for the secure and the normal site, or the one cookie u use for your shopping cart can't have the secure flag, in which case you really don't need https in my opinion. Also, you will never be able to implement HSTS.

You've already gone to the lengths bought a certificate and set up an https-server, now why not secure the whole site?

Update to answer your question in the comment:

1. That is of course a deal-breaker, if you rely on those and the hosts haven't implemented https yes (which they probably will sooner or later, or they are going to be out of business)
   Depending on what they actually do, you maybe could proxy the request to those scripts and serve them from you https-enabled server. But I would really consider this last a resort.
2. The slowing down part is mostly just the handshake. If you enable session resumption there shouldn't be too much overhead to actually slow down your site. Make sure your TLS session cache is big enough and that the ticket lifetime is ample.
   Of course, your mileage may vary. So make sure you test your https site before going online.
3. I heard of such horror stories as well, but I think most of the time it's probably due to faulty or at least sub-standard implementation. Make sure you redirect EVERY single http-request to https with the 301 status and you should be fine. For some months now enabling https should actually help with your Google pagerank.
4. To link to an external site (differnt FQDN) you don't have to implement any trickery to avoid browser warnings - that's just linking to a different site and has nothing to do with mixed content policies.

Comment: after chewing on your suggestions, the concerns I have with converting whole site over to secure:

Comment: After chewing on your suggestions, the concerns I have with converting whole site over to secure: 1. we have a lot of links to external scripts in WordPress and phpBB that are to non secure sites 2. I've seen where secure sites can slow page speed 3. I've seen where switching from http to https can effect page rank in search engines. Maybe these factors are aren't so anymore, and maybe I can somehow find and edit the external links in wordpress, ect. I assume links to regular sites (for example to stackoverflow.com) have to run through https-2-http redirects? Thanks for any suggestions.